# Edit sql file to secure credentials during deployment of project in azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using an [open source tool](https://docs.getdbt.com/) for deployment of schema for my warehouse snowflake. I have successfully done it for tables, views and procedures. Currently I'm facing an issue, I have to deploy snowflake stages same way. But stages required url and azure saas token when you define it in your sql file like this:

```
CREATE or replace STAGE myStage
URL = 'azure://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/'
CREDENTIALS = ( AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' )
file_format = myFileFormat;
```

As it is not encouraged to use your credentials in file that will be published on version control and access by others. Is there a way/task in azure devOps so I can just pass a template SQL file in repo and change it before compilation and execution(may be via azure key vault) and change back to template? So these credentials and token always remain secure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a STORAGE INTEGRATION, instead?  If you use the storage integration credentials and grant that to your Blob storage, then you'd be able to create STAGE objects without passing any credentials at all.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html

Comment: In that way I'll have to deploy storage integration via ci/cd process too and that will use azure_tenant_id in my sql file and further expose this with others. Do you think, is this safe to expose azure_tenant_id?

Comment: Well, depending on the complexity of your security model, you could potentially create a single integration object upfront, and then just use that integration object in all of your stage definitions that you are creating from your ci/cd process.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue ,you can use credential-less stages to secure your cloud storage without sharing secrets.

Here agree with **Mike**, [storage integrations](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html), a new object type, allow a Snowflake administrator to create a trust policy between Snowflake and the cloud provider. When Snowflake connects to the organization’s cloud storage, the cloud provider authenticates and authorizes access through this trust policy.

Storage integrations and credential-less external stages put into the administrator’s hands the power of connecting to storage in a secure and manageable way. This functionality is now generally available in Snowflake.

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/use-credential-less-stages-to-secure-your-cloud-storage-without-sharing-secrets/). In addition, you can also via azure key vault, key vault provides a secure place for accessing and storing secrets.

Comment: I agreed after reading docs and blog you have shared about storage integration. Storage integration looks promising but I am doing all this with ci/cd pipelines and using an open source tool. So I will have to deploy **storage integration** as well with this process and in storage integration as mentioned in docs I will have to define azure_tenant_id while creating it. This will be exposed too to the other persons. Is this safe to expose azure_tenant_id?